# How can the "Optimize code" option in a C# project cause a crash in native code?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, debugging, c++-cli

I have a Windows Forms application that uses SQLite files as a file format. The files are created by native code which is called via C++/CLI wrappers which includes callbacks to the managed code for progress/cancellation updates. This has been working great for 32-bit. I'm trying to remove my memory ceiling by switching to 64-bit and have run into a major snag.

I get pseudo-deterministic crashes when memory is being allocated or deallocated inside the native code, which makes me think of memory corruption. But it only happens during release builds and only without the debugger attached. Here's a breakdown of my nightmare:

```
Config   Bits Optimizations Interop Dbg-symbols Runtime With-debugger Without-debugger
Release   32     on           no       no         /MD    no crash         no crash
Release   64     on           yes      no         /MD    no crash         no crash
Release   32     on           yes      no         /MD    no crash         no crash
Release   64     on           yes      no         /MD    no crash          crash
Release   64     on           yes      yes        /MD    no crash          crash
Release   64     off          yes      no         /MD    no crash         no crash
Release   64     off          yes      yes        /MD    no crash         no crash
Debug     32     off          no       yes        /MDd   no crash         no crash
Debug     32     off          yes      yes        /MDd   no crash         no crash
Debug     64     off          yes      yes        /MDd   no crash         no crash
Debug     64     on           yes      yes        /MD    no crash         no crash
Debug     64     on           yes      no         /MD    no crash         no crash
Debug     64     off          yes      yes        /MD    no crash         no crash
Debug     64     off          yes      yes        /MDd   no crash         no crash
Debug     64     on           yes      yes        /MDd   no crash         no crash
Debug     64     on           yes      no         /MD    no crash         no crash
```

"Interop" means that I'm using the C++/CLI wrappers from the GUI application to run the native parser code. I have a command-line driver that is written in native C++ and that doesn't crash in any configuration.

Basically the debug config never crashes, even when the native code is compiled EXACTLY LIKE RELEASE CODE! I've compared the response files, they are the same, except I added _NO_DEBUG_HEAP=1 for the debug configs. I doubt that has any impact anyway when using /MD and defining NDEBUG. So how do I debug this nightmare? It doesn't feel like it's a problem with my code. Please don't ask for a small repro, I have no idea how to make it. But the code is all open source, so if anybody wants to try to reproduce this I'll post a link to the source.

---

Update: I have discovered that the crash can be avoided by turning off "Optimize code" in the C# project (which is why the debug config with native optimizations works fine). How the hell can that cause a crash in the native code?!

Comment: Add `Trace::WriteLine` to isolate crash to specific location. Once you know the location, you will figure out the cause.

Comment: @RomanR.: How could I add that in the native code? I've used logging to isolate the crash to certain sections of the code; that's how I know it probably has something to do with allocating or deallocating memory. One config was crashing when clearing a vector<shared_ptr<std::string> >, but that actually shouldn't have freed any memory, it should have just decremented the ref-count for all the ptrs (they were all held elsewhere). I wish it was that easy. :(

Comment: This sounds like an uninitialized stack variable on the native side. When optimization is disabled, the part of the stack that gets initialized by the .NET side can differ from when it is on.

Comment: Also, check if [pinning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f58wzh21(v=vs.100).aspx) might be needed.

Answer (score 0):

Heisenbugs are normally caused by memory stomps (which can't happen in managed code) or by treating trash in memory as valid data.

I have hunted multiple generally reproducible heisenbugs that came down to using an uninitialized variable that would pick up whatever had been on the stack from another routine.  Your native code could contain such a bug that works when it gets one value and blows up when it gets another.  Debug vs release doesn't guarantee the stuff behind the scenes will be the same (after all, if it was why would there be the two configurations?) and you could have different trash in memory.

The optimizer could also have such effects.

One thing I would try:  Slap a substantial structure into the local variables of the first routine in the native code.  Do something with it to keep the linker from stripping it.

This will move things around, if it's a trash in memory problem this should change the behavior.

Comment: Why wouldn't such a bug in the native code be caught by the debug heap in my non-Interop cases?

Comment: @MattChambers:  The other version might be leaving acceptable stuff in memory.